# How to express "to the extent of my ability" after receiving a recommendation letter?

Tags: sentence-usage

I asked and received a letter of recommendation from someone outside my company. This person is considered an expert in the field, and has much more experience than me (decades v. years).

I am very grateful for his letter, and would like to say something like:

> If and when you need it, I will be happy to return the favor **to the extent of my ability**.

As this person is so much more experienced than I am, I don’t have any idea as to how to express this in a respectful way. I don’t know how I would be returning this favor in the future, nor how much value it can bring to him.

The goal is to express that I am grateful. Can you tell me what would be an appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> If and when you need it, I will be happy to return the favor to the extent of my ability.

You could use *to the best of my ability*.

> to the best of your ability

> PHRASE

> If you do something to the best of your abilities or to the best of your ability, you do it as well as you can.

> I take care of them to the best of my abilities.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-the-best-of-your-ability)